# linking to View inside fragment

Tags: android, button, fragment

I am beginner in android
I was following a lesson on the internet about Fragment
the idea is that you have two fragments:
one containing button the other containing textview
in the lesson the he linked to the button and text view under
onActivityCreated(...){...}

But I did the same task as follow(button sample)

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
Communicator comm;
Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr1_layout, container, false);
    button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            comm.respond("Button was clickede");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

and it worked for me

which procedure is correct

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView()` is meant to return the view associated with the fragment, no further logic.

`onActivityCreated()` means that the associated activity has completed its method onCreate().

You should implement your logic in `onActivityCreated()`. You can access the inflated layout by calling `getView()`.

```
button=(Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

see also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html (Lifecycle)